# Is it possible in objective c to define multiple values?

Tags: objective-c

To define multiple values such as
define number 3,4   in objective c? And have it randomly chosen?

Comment: Im actually at friends house without a mac or any objective c program. But I was wondering if this was possible. I am trying to find out online ,but not get any results. By the sound of your comment it looks possible.

Comment: It definitely is possible @DrummerB has given a good answer. Beat me to it. This just sounds like a homework question that I have seen before and many users don't like doing peoples homework for them.

Comment: actually not what I meant. I am saying if it was like "#define number 3"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int r = 3 + arc4random() % 2;
```

`arc4random() % 2` returns either 0 or 1 randomly. Adding 3 will make it chose randomly between 3 and 4.

Comment: what if it is like this "#define number 1"

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to define random preprocessor macros.

Comment: I needed a method to do this for a certain project. I will figure out another way.

Comment: @DrummerB `arcrandom()` is for cryptography. It's massive overkill for most uses. For simple random numbers you should use `random` seeded with `srandom`.